# Every time I save my plugin options it erases another plugin options

Tags: plugins, options

I created two plugins, when I save one settings it completely erases the settings from the other one, and it also happens the other way round.

I really don't understand what the issue might be about since they don't share the same general configuration: one plugin options are saved in pl_popup_options and the other in pl_analytics_options. Yet when I update the first one, it erases the value of the other from the database.

Anybody faced a similar issue? What could be the reason for this?

Plugin 1

```
class PLAnalyticsSettings
{
    /**
     * Holds the values to be used in the fields callbacks
     */
    private $options;

    /**
     * Start up
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        add_action( 'admin_menu', array( $this, 'add_plugin_page' ) );
        add_action( 'admin_init', array( $this, 'page_init' ) );
    }

    /**
     * Add options page
     */
    public function add_plugin_page()
    {
        // This page will be under "Settings"
        add_options_page(
            'Settings Admin', 
            'Pranalog Analytics', 
            'manage_options', 
            'pl_analytics_options', 
            array( $this, 'create_admin_page' )
        );
    }

    /**
     * Options page callback
     */
    public function create_admin_page()
    {
        // Set class property
        $this->options = get_option( 'pl_analytics' );
        ?>
        <div class="wrap">
            <?php screen_icon(); ?>
            <h2>Pranalog Analytics Settings</h2>           
            <form method="post" action="options.php">
            <?php
                // This prints out all hidden setting fields
                settings_fields( 'my_option_group' );   
                do_settings_sections( 'pl_analytics_options' );
                submit_button(); 
            ?>
            </form>
        </div>
        <?php
    }

    /** 
     * Print the Section text
     */
    public function print_section_info()
    {
        print 'Ingresa el código debajo y se añadirá en el header a computadoras que no hayan registrado un admin:';
    }

    /**
     * Register and add settings
     */
    public function page_init()
    {        
        register_setting(
            'my_option_group', // Option group
            'pl_analytics', // Option name
            array( $this, 'sanitize' ) // Sanitize
        );

        add_settings_section(
            'general_settings', // ID
            'Pranalog Analytics', // Title
            array( $this, 'print_section_info' ), // Callback
            'pl_analytics_options' // Page
        );  

        add_settings_field(
            'code', // ID
            'Código', // Title
            array( $this, 'code_callback' ), // Callback
            'pl_analytics_options',  // Page
            'general_settings' // Section ID
        );      
    }

    /**
     * Sanitize each setting field as needed
     *
     * @param array $input Contains all settings fields as array keys
     */
    public function sanitize( $input )
    {
        // TODO: Sanitize
        return $input;
    }

    /** 
     * Get the settings option array and print one of its values
     */
    public function code_callback()
    {
        printf('<textarea type="text" id="code" name="pl_analytics[code]" style="min-width: 80%%; max-width: 80%%; min-height: 250px; max-height: 400px; font-size: 12px;">%s</textarea>',
        isset($this->options['code']) ? esc_attr( $this->options['code']) : ''
        );
    }
}

if(is_admin())
    $pla_settings_page = new PLAnalyticsSettings();
```

Plugin 2

```
class PLPopupSettings
{
    /**
     * Holds the values to be used in the fields callbacks
     */
    private $options;

    /**
     * Start up
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        add_action( 'admin_menu', array( $this, 'add_plugin_page' ) );
        add_action( 'admin_init', array( $this, 'page_init' ) );
    }

    /**
     * Add options page
     */
    public function add_plugin_page()
    {
        // This page will be under "Settings"
        add_options_page(
            'Settings Admin', 
            'Pranalog Popup', 
            'manage_options', 
            'pl_popup_options', 
            array( $this, 'create_admin_page' )
        );
    }

    /**
     * Options page callback
     */
    public function create_admin_page()
    {
        // Set class property
        $this->options = get_option( 'pl_popup' );
        ?>
        <div class="wrap">
            <?php screen_icon(); ?>
            <h2>Pranalog Popup Settings</h2>           
            <form method="post" action="options.php">
            <?php
                // This prints out all hidden setting fields
                settings_fields( 'my_option_group' );   
                do_settings_sections( 'pl_popup_options' );
                submit_button(); 
            ?>
            </form>
        </div>
        <?php
    }

    /** 
     * Print the Section text
     */
    public function print_section_info()
    {
        print 'Pranalog Popup te permite mostrar un popup personalizado en todo tu sitio';
    }

    /**
     * Register and add settings
     */
    public function page_init()
    {        
        register_setting(
            'my_option_group', // Option group
            'pl_popup', // Option name
            array( $this, 'sanitize' ) // Sanitize
        );

        add_settings_section(
            'general_settings', // ID
            'Pranalog Popup', // Title
            array( $this, 'print_section_info' ), // Callback
            'pl_popup_options' // Page
        );  

        add_settings_field(
            'enabled', // ID
            'Activado', // Title
            array( $this, 'enabled_callback' ), // Callback
            'pl_popup_options',  // Page
            'general_settings' // Section ID
        );   

        add_settings_field(
            'content', // ID
            'Contenido del Popup', // Title
            array( $this, 'content_callback' ), // Callback
            'pl_popup_options',  // Page
            'general_settings' // Section ID
        );      
    }

    /**
     * Sanitize each setting field as needed
     *
     * @param array $input Contains all settings fields as array keys
     */
    public function sanitize( $input )
    {
        // TODO: Sanitize
        return $input;
    }

    /** 
     * Get the settings option array and print one of its values
     */
    public function enabled_callback()
    {
        // echo the field
        printf(
            '<input type="checkbox" id="enabled" value="checked" name="pl_popup[enabled]" %s/>',
            isset( $this->options['enabled'] ) ? esc_attr( $this->options['enabled']) : ''
        );
    }

    public function content_callback()
    {
        printf(
                '<textarea type="text" id="content" name="pl_popup[content]" style="min-width: 80%%; max-width: 80%%; min-height: 250px; max-height: 400px; font-size: 12px;">%s</textarea>',
                isset($this->options['content']) ? esc_attr( $this->options['content']) : ''
            );
    }
}

if(is_admin())
    $plp_settings_page = new PLPopupSettings();
```

Comment: What are the contents of the `create_admin_page` function? Both of your options pages reference that function, so presumably you're not differentiating between the two option pages within. The 4th argument of `add_options_page` is menu slug, it has nothing to do with what key your options are saved under.

Comment: There's no enough here to work from. Are these within the same class or different? What's in the create_admin_page method?

Answer (score 1):

The [`add_options_page()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_options_page) **adds an option page** under Settings menu. It **does not add an option**. You're registering your settings/options using other functions. Either [`add_option()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_option), [`add_settings_field()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_settings_field) or [`register_setting()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_setting).

Both your options are saved with the same **option name**, thus overriding each other. You need to save each of them with different option names.

Comment: hi Andrei, I just copied the code. I don't think they are overriding each other I see two records on the database one for each plugin. Yet when I save one plugin the other record's becomes blank.